# Excel - Is it possible to COUNTA an entire column when you're getting the column letter from a ADDRESS match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, cell

I have a series of team lists, with the manager as the header and their team members listed below them.

On another sheet I have a summary, which lists all the manages vertically and the count of their team members next to them.

I'm trying to make this dynamic, as the team managers and team sizes will change all the time.

Currently I'm using this formula to get the column letter of the referenced manager name and feeding that into the COUNTA function but it's always returning 1?

```
=COUNTA("Teams!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(J4, mtch_teams, 0),4),1,"")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(J4, mtch_teams, 0),4),1,""))
```

For context, 'mtch_teams' is the single-row named range I created to use with MATCH. When I evaluate the formula it knits together and the end result is this:

```
=COUNTA("Teams!F:F")
```

I'm thinking the range reference being in speech marks is what's causing the problem but the formula doesn't error so I'm not sure what to do?

Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: Doing this getting the column letter sounds like a long roundabout route to your goal. Furthermore, your current formula isn't syntax-correct. You'd miss an `INDIRECT()` which I'd advise against since it's volatile too. Do you have sample data (simplified) with expected results? This can probably be done much simpler.

Comment: You can try indirect() to produce the range.

Comment: No need for the Indirect stuff. Try
 something like `COUNTA(INDEX(Teams!A:Z, MATCH(J4, mtch_teams, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Placing an indirect( <.> , 1) within the counta will work*; screenshot(s) refer:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(J4, {"Sheet1"}, 0),4),1,"")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(J4, {"Sheet1"}, 0),4),1,""),1))
```

[image: Indirect within counta]

The reason as to why your current approach evaluates to '1' is indeed because of the inverted commas, i.e. "Teams!F:F" within your Counta is being evaluated as the count of the number of elements that comprise the series `{"Teams!F:F"}`.  *Likewise `counta("Teams!F:F","Teams!G:G")` would evaluate to 2 etc.*

As mentioned by others in the comments preceeding; indirect is volatile and difficult to audit / trace back. However, sometimes the desired functionality within Excel warrants the use of this (e.g. if the intention is for a user to specify a sheet name, cell row/column from anywhere within the workbook, then indirect would probably be the best way to return the corresponding cell value - challenges welcome in this regard and would be new news to me!).

Ta,

Notes: (*) assuming what you have included within the counta at present is correct/legitimate.